# c# Перемещение контрола

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Суть задачи: мне нужно влево-вправо немного подвигать контрол при нажатии кнопки (буквально на 15 поинтов). "А-ля анимация в WinForms".
Возможно ли в WinForms их вообще программно перемещать без артефактов и плавно (хоть как-нибудь...). Вся моя реализация:

```
    private async Task Shake(Control control)
    {
        var startPos = control.Location;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            control.Location = new Point(control.Location.X + i,control.Location.Y);
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
            {
                control.Location = new Point(control.Location.X - j, control.Location.Y);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
            {
                control.Location = new Point(control.Location.X + j, control.Location.Y);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
            }
        }

        control.Location = startPos;
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Shake(mainTextBox); //textbox
    }
```

Весь "прикол" в том, что либо это происходит слишком быстро, что даже не заметно, либо с артефактами (в формате "частичек" этого контрола) (мб выглядит слишком "колхозно", но постарался хоть как-нибудь реализовать, т.к. впервые с конкретно этой темой сталкиваюсь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите контролировать скорость, то двигать надо в таймере. Вот примерный код на коленке (Все контролы создаются в рантайме, на форму кидать ничего не нужно. По нажатию одной кнопки другая плавно двигается вправо.)

```
    Timer mover = new Timer();//Таймер
    Button button1 = new Button();//Контрол, который мы будем двигать
    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mover.Interval = 1;//Интервал передвижения в миллисекундах
        Button button = new Button();//Кнопка по нажатию которой мы будем запускать таймер
        button.Location = new Point(40, 40);//Позиция вышеописанной кнопки
        button.Size = new Size(100, 40);//Её размер
        button.Text = "Move";//Е текст
        button.Click += new EventHandler(butLabel_Click);//Обработчик события клика
        Controls.Add(button);//Добавление этой кнопки на форму

        button1.Location = new Point(100, 100);//Позиция двигающегося контрола
        button1.Size = new Size(40, 40);//Его размер
        Controls.Add(button1);//Добавляем на форму
    }

    private void butLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Метод описывающий действия, происходящие по нажатию первой кнопки
    {
        mover.Tick += TimerDoWork;//Обработчик события каждого тика таймера
        mover.Enabled = true;//Включаем таймер
        mover.Start();//Запускаем таймер
    }

    private void TimerDoWork(object sender, EventArgs e)//Метод, описывающий действия, которые будут происходить при каждом тике таймера
    {
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X + 1, button1.Location.Y);//Преемещение двигающегося контрола на 1 пиксель вправо
    }
```

Comment: Реализация с таймером помогла. Стало двигаться чуть мягче, но я всё равно всё это запихал через потоки, т.к. мне не нужно создавать объект, а двигать существующие (в данный момент объекта 2, но, если их будет больше, то писать тонну повторяющегося кода - так себе показатель...)

Comment: Если у Вас куча готовых объектов, передавайте их в таймер в качестве параметра, чтобы сама логика таймера понимала, что именно Вам надо двигать. Таймеры можно плодить бесконечно. Засовывать таймеры в потоки нет смысла, так как все таймеры выполняются в ThreadingPool по умолчанию.